# pick an image and upload it automatically

Tags: php, jquery

I want to click on a button and open the file browser from a local disc and automatically upload the selected file to remote server.

```
<input hidden type="file" id="loader" accept="image/*">
```

**js**

```
$('#m1new').click(function(){
    $('#loader').click();
});
$('#loader').change(function(){
var img = this.files[0];
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'img': img},
    success: function() {
        console.log('ok');
    }
}); 
});
```

**upload.php**  (updated)

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

Console:
`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FormData` to send multipart requests and you should set `processData` option to `false`  to preven automatic processing

```
$('#loader').change(function(event){
  var img = event.target.files[0];
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('img', img);
  $.ajax({
      url: 'upload.php',
      processData: false,
      type: 'post',
      data: formData,
      success: function() {
        console.log('ok');
      }
  }); 
});
```

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: there is no error in console now, and console says `ok`, but still there is no img in `uploads` folder. Could you check my php code, pls?

Comment: @bonaca files should be in `$_FILES` array now , just change `$_POST['img'];` to `$_FILES['img'];`

Comment: I changed `$img = $_POST['img'];` to `$img = $_FILES['img'];` but still there is no img uploaded in `uploads` folder. `ok` in the console is there.

Comment: Are you sure that you request successfully sent to server ?

Comment: sucess function works - `ok` is in written in console - should be ok with sending request.